# certbot renew in the wrong folder

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

When I do

```
certbot certonly --force-renew -d mywebsite.com
```

It creates a new cert into the wrong folder, adding `-0001`. And it says:

```
Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com-0001/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com-0001/privkey.pem
```

And of course the folder `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com` is not updated.

How can I force certbot to renew in the good folder?

Of course after `service nginx reload`, when I check the cert in Chrome on mywebsite.com there is no change.

In the NGinx conf, I have:

```
server {

  server_name mywebsite.com;

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
```

Comment: The first cert was created 2 months ago, doing ```sudo certbot --nginx -d mywebsite.com -d www.mywebsite.com```. It sould auto reload but it'll during hollidays, so I'd like to force reload before, by security.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are `certonly` when you should be using `renew`. And it is installing a duplicate certificate not renewing the existing.

When you get the initial certificate you can get it using the above command. It is interactive to the user (or you can make it --non-interactive)

Renewal process is automatic. `certbot renew` command will check for all certificates that are about to expire in /etc/letsencrypt/ (or whatever directory you tell certbot to use) and it will renew those that are nearing expiry. You run the renew command from cron and it's ok to run it daily or so - it will not really renew anything until certificates are about to expire.